# Search a pattern in multiple files and replace existing match with increment by one

Tags: perl

I've around 200 files, all the files have same values. Now wanted to search a pattern and
replace the match character.

Example:

`file01.txt`:

```
1,51:495600    
118,1:20140924105028    

file02.txt have    
1,51:495600    
118,1:20140924105028
```

... and so on until `file200.txt`.

Our result should be:

`file01.txt`:

```
1,51:495601  /* each file ':number' will be incremented by one    
118,1:20140924105228 /* each file 11th and 12th position character will be incremented  by 02
```

`file02.txt`:

```
1,51:495602  /* each file ':number' will be incremented by one    
118,1:20140924105428 /* each file 11th and 12th position character will be incremented  by 02 

for earlier it was 50 now it will incremented by 52 , 53 , 54 like that max will be  60    
e.g..
file01.txt     
118,1:20140924105028 ;    
file02.txt     
118,1:20140924105228 ;    
file03.txt     
118,1:20140924105428 ;    
file04.txt     
118,1:20140924105628 ;    
file05.txt    
118,1:20140924105828 ;
```

As I'm very new in Perl, I need help to create the script.

Find below Script.

```
foreach $file (@files)
{
  open(file , "$file");    #open file
  while($line = <file>)       #read file
  {
    print "$line" if $line =~ /1,51:495600/;       #find patten
    perl -pi'.backup' -e 's/(^1,51:495600)/^1,51:/g' $file
    #find and replace and take a backup of file
  }
  close;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the behaviour of the second line. Characters 11 and 12 are `50`. It sounds like you want to add 2 to this in the first file, 3 in the second etc. but your *example* adds 2 in the first file, 4 in the second, 6 in the third etc. What do you mean by *“max will be 60”*? What happens after this field reaches `60` in `file09.txt` (or `file05.txt` depending on the algorithm).

Comment: 118,1:20140924105028   

If we break field “20140924105028”, it can be understandable as mentioned below:   
   
2014 09 24 10 50 28   
yyyy mm dd hh24 mi ss   
   
Now idea is to increase minute (which is in above case is 50) by 2 min until it reaches to 60. Once it reaches to 60, hour column should increase by additional 1 hour (which in this case would be 11) and the minute counter should start with 00,02, 04,....60.
Example:-   
118,1:20140924105228   
118,1:20140924105428   
118,1:20140924105628   
118,1:20140924105828   
118,1:20140924110028   
118,1:20140924110228   
.   
.  
.  
So on.

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you ask. It uses the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module to manipulate the date/time field so that hour boundaries and midnights are handled correctly. This has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5 and so shouldn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;     # For autodie and regex \K
use autodie;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_MINUTE /;

use constant DATE_FORMAT => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S';

my $n;

for my $file (@files) {

  open my $in_fh, '<', $file;
  my @lines = <$in_fh>;
  close $in_fh;

  ++$n;
  $lines[0] =~ s/^\d+,\d+:\K(\d+)/$1+$n/e;
  $lines[1] =~ s{^\d+,\d+:\K(\d+)}{
    my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($1, DATE_FORMAT);
    ($tp + ONE_MINUTE * 2 * $n)->strftime(DATE_FORMAT);
  }e;

  my $backup = "$file.backup";
  unlink $backup if -f $backup;
  rename $file, $backup;

  open my $out_fh, '>', $file;
  print $out_fh @lines;
  close $out_fh;
}
```

Comment: With `perl, v5.10.1` I get `Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at … line 13.`